# Imagepicker not displaying the array of images. What is the solution?

Tags: angularjs, image, view, base64, photo-gallery

I am using image picker plugin to select images and display it as a slide. The view part doesnt work. I am getting only img icon and not the images. I have used base64 plugin to convert to base64. I am working on this for more than a week. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

contoller.js

```
  $scope.photoData = [];
   $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function(results) {
      function successFunc(base64) {
          console.log('photoData: ' + base64);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          $scope.photoData.push(results[i]);
          window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(results[i], successFunc);
          console.log(results[i]);
                   }
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
          $scope.$apply();
      }
  }, function(err) {
      // An error occured. Show a message to the user
  });
                };
```

html

```
 <div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in photoData">
    <img ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{item}}" style="max-width: 100%">
     </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: does `console.log('photoData: ' + base64);` log the correct data?

Comment: i get a long data url in the console which i get similar to the cordova camera option(the camera option works)